# Converting a lambda function to a functor structure with mixed lambda-introducer and parameter list

Tags: c++, lambda, functor

I'm trying to replace a lambda expression with a functor structor (in order to apply some attributes onto it).
I'm hitting some trouble - what am I doing wrong?:

```
void foo_top(std::unique_ptr<type_b> b)
{
    type_a a{};

#if 0 // I want to replace this original lambda:
    foo([a, b = std::move(b)](uint8_t c) mutable {
        a.foo_on_c(c);
        b->foo_on_a(a);
    });
#else // Trying to replace with an equivalent functor. My attempt:
    struct d_functor {                                                                              
        type_a d_a;
        std::unique_ptr<type_b> d_b;

        d_functor(type_a a, std::unique_ptr<type_b> b) : d_a(a) {
            d_b = std::move(b);
        }
        void operator()(uint8_t c) mutable { // Getting errors here...
            d_a.foo_on_c(c);
            d_b->foo_on_a(d_a);
        }
    };
    foo(d_functor{a, b});
#endif
}
```

Getting errors:

```
error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
             void operator()(uint8_t c) mutable {
error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
             void operator()(uint8_t c) mutable {
```

Comment: There is no `mutable` qualifier for member functions. What exactly is the reason you are doing this? You can apply attributes to lambdas.

Comment: How would I make the mutable part of the lambda equivalent in the functor?

Answer (score 3):

There is no `mutable` qualifier for member functions. As long as the `const` qualifier is not used, member functions can modify members of the class.

Therefore a call operator without `const` is equivalent to a `mutable` lambda and a call operator with `const` qualifier is equivalent to a lambda without `mutable`.